# I can't start nfs in SLES 11

Tags: nfs, sles

I'm trying to start nfs service in my SLES.

I have my `/etc/exports` like this:

```
/var/share/testbed *(ro)
```

When I run `service nfs start`, it says:

```
Not starting NFS client services - no NFS found in /etc/fstab:
```

For  `service nfs status`, it says:

```
Checking for mounted nfs shares (from /etc/fstab):idmapd not running
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'service nfs' (`/etc/init.d/nfs`) is the NFS client. To start the NFS server, you have to use `service nfsserver start`

You might need to install `nfs-kernel-server` package (unless it is already installed).

Comment: wow. I made a stupid mistake. Thank you, Petr.